# Create mvn project including properties and dependencies

Tags: maven, project

How can I create a Maven project with some properties and dependencies set?

E.g. when creating a project via:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app \
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

how can I add

```
  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
```

?

I know that I could use the command from above a use some string manipulation commands. However, I want to know if there is any Maven way to either directly create a pom.xml with properties and dependencies set or to add them later on, e.g. something like:

```
mvn <add-properties> -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.7 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.7
mvn <add-dependency> -DgroupId=org.json -DartifactId=json -Dversion=20090211
```

Comment: I suppose you already know how to set the properties directly in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Wow! You mean with a text editor...?! :) No, I need a command since I need it for a script.

Comment: Then you should either: make your own archetype or use a scripting language to manipulate the XML generated by the archetype. Making your own plugin is also a solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't think](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Is-there-any-maven-plugin-to-add-dependency-to-existing-pom-xml-td2839092.html) maven has this feature OOTB.

You can also use a generic XML utility tool e.g. [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php).

Adding properties:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 \
-s /x:project -t elem -n properties -v "" \
-s /x:project/properties -t elem -n maven.compiler.source -v 1.7 \
-s /x:project/properties -t elem -n maven.compiler.target -v 1.7 \
pom.xml
```

Adding a dependency:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 \
-s /x:project/x:dependencies -t elem -n dependency -v "" \
-s "/x:project/x:dependencies/dependency[last()]" -t elem -n groupId -v org.json \
-s "/x:project/x:dependencies/dependency[last()]" -t elem -n artifactId -v json \
-s "/x:project/x:dependencies/dependency[last()]" -t elem -n version -v 2009211 \
pom.xml
```

Read this if you have questions regarding the x namespace I used: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html.

Depending on the scenario, creating your own archetype like what @Tome had said might be a better option.