# Bash insert subnode to XML file

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed, xmlstarlet

Im trying to edit a config file using bash. My file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I want to add another couple of `<property>` blocks to the file. Since all `property` tags are enclosed inside the `configuration` tags the file would looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I came across [this post and followed the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234681/adding-xml-element-in-xml-file-using-sed-command-in-shell-script), however nothing is appended to my file and the xml block I try to append is "echo-ed" as a single line string.
My bash file looks like this:

```
file=/path/to/file/oozie-site.xml
content="<property>\n<name></name>\n<value></value>\n</property>\n<property>\n<name></name>\n<value></value>\n</property>"
echo $content
C=$(echo $content | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
sed "/<\/configuration>/ s/.*/${C}\n&/" $file
```

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
  -s '//configuration' -t elem -n "property" \
  -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "name" \
  -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" \
  file.xml
```

Output:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name/>
    <value/>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name/>
    <value/>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name/>
    <value/>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

---

> `--omit-decl`: omit XML declaration
>
> `-s`: add a subnode (see [`xmlstarlet edit`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320) for details)
>
> `-t elem`: set node type, here: element
>
> `-n`: set name of element

Comment: trying this out - when I run this command, it prints out my config file in the terminal with the added subnode. However when I check the file out in vim nothing seems to be appended

Comment: Nvm . I added file.xml > newfile.xml and see the changes. thanks a lot. One final question, how to add multiple blocks? just have more these `-s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" \` ?

Comment: If there's a namespace defined, you need to specify it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615428/create-mvn-project-including-properties-and-dependencies/17626924#17626924

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line by `sed -i.BAK "/<\/configuration>/ s/.*/${C}\n&/" $file`

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful with some explanation.